# Add-Ins for Office365: inserting data into an excel sheet from a task-pane add-in

Tags: excel, office365, office-addins, office-js

I must be missing something:

[problem]:

I have a 2-dimensional array of data, that i would like to insert into the current sheet starting from cell A1. I also have to format this data.
The current document may be empty or not. I do not have control over this.

At a later point, i need to remove the data from the document and insert new data. This new set of data may have different dimensions.

This seems to be impossible to do using the Office JavaScript Api.

All the things I tried using TableBindings, etc. have failed. In many cases, functionality that should work according to MSDN failed, giving me cryptic error messages such as "internal error" (code 5001) or unsupported binding operation (3010). I have to use tablebindings, because i can't apply formatting to anything else according to the MSDN documentation.

The following solutions are unacceptable:

- forcing the user to use a specific document template with preexisting named tables
- forcing the user to select cell "A1" before my Add-In gets to work.
- forcing the user to select a range prior to inserting the data.

All of which are nightmarish solutions from a usability point-of-view.

I *can* create a binding from named item and construct the range by counting columns and rows and building a string like this "A1:C232" but this only works once, because:

- i can't delete the data (yes. calling "deleteAllDataValuesAsync" on a binding  created with such a named range throws error 3010 (even though the binding say's it's a "table" binding.. wat?).
- i can't overwrite it with data of different size (overwrite error)
- i can't set formatting on it (yes, it's a binding created as a tablebinding, yes, i can call the setFormatAsync function, and it throws an "internal error, 5001" -> #headdesk

I hope someone from Microsoft reads this and can point me in the right direction. I really hope! Because i'm starting to fear that this is actually by design. (i'm so frustrated by office.js after the last few weeks of struggle, i'm having a hard time not ranting, so i'll stop right here.. don't get me started on ui fabric)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the new Excel Javascript APIs introduced with Office 2016 (and available soon in Office Online), it is easy to manipulate worksheet data using the new Range object. The snippet below runs without requiring range selection or any other action on the part of the user.

```js
var data = [
    [1,2,3],
    [2,6,7]
]

Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    // make space for the data to be inserted
    var sheet1 = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    var firstCell = sheet1.getCell(0,0);
    var lastCell = sheet1.getCell(data.length - 1, data[0].length - 1);
    var range = firstCell.getBoundingRect(lastCell).insert('down');

    range.values = data; // insert data
    range.format.font.bold = true;

    range.delete('up'); // erase data, shift up
    return ctx.sync();
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Try it out in the Office JS Snippet explorer and see the blog post linked below for more info!

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippet-explorer

https://dev.office.com/blogs/Office-js-Public-Preview

Comment: Wow! that is **exactly** how i'd expect the Api to work and look. way cleaner than what we have right now. This will not be ported to Office 2013, will it? (i suppose that would require changes to office itself in the form of an update/service pack, right?)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know of any plans to port the new API to Office '13 and earlier. But if you have an O365 subscription, you can uprade to Office 16 at no additional cost. In addition, the new API will be ported to Office Online and Mac/iOS soon.  [link](http://dev.office.com/blogs/Office-js-Public-Preview)